# Is possible to use functor as template parameter to std::function?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, c++11, porting

I am trying to find what g++ compiler parameters to use for compiling this sample c++ code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <functional>

struct mystruct
{
    int a;
    int operator()(int y) { return y + 1; }
};

int main()
{
    std::function<mystruct> foo;
    return 0;
}
```

In cpp reference is written that std::function template parameter can be "...or other function objects". I work on large project containing several std::function and project is buildable with g++. I am trying to build it under VS2015 but compiler on such code complains:

error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::_Get_function_impl<_Fty>'
          with
          [
              _Fty=mystruct
          ]

when I try to compile above small sample under g++ with -std=c++11 it also comlains:

error: aggregate 'std::function a' has incomplete type and cannot be defined

So I think in our large buildable project g++ probably has switched some extension which provides such capability.

Comment: Where do you see that the template parameter can be anything other than a function type (e.g., `int(double, char)`)? cppreference says it can *store* function objects. Anyway, what would it do if `mystruct` had more than one `operator()` overload, or if `operator()` were templated? it can't safely type-erase a call signature.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you mixed up the template argument with a function object to be stored. I believe what did you want to write is

```
std::function<int(int)> foo{mystruct{}};
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is that functor cannot be template parameter to other functor. Thanks for all posts.